# What architectural pattern(s) should I use for my RIA?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-applications, javascript-framework, dom-events

I'm building a web application that interacts heavily with the DOM and need direction in making my code scalable and maintainable.

The application overview: Upon interaction, I have toolbars and overlays that guide the user to edit the page, I then send back the edited page to the server.

So far I've successfully built what I wanted but it's JQuery all tied together and I need help on how to rewrite my code to make it scalable and maintainable.

Research so far:

- RequireJS - I've looked at RequireJS and thought this was a great starting point and got it all working.
- JQuery - Can't get away from this awesome library.
- Nicholas Zakas' presentation on Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture - Awesome idea, but how do I implement this? I'm fairly new to advanced JavaScript.

I will also need some kind of event pooling to manage all these events. If I use JQuery's built-in event pooling "bind", "trigger", will this not force me away from Zakas' idea that only my application core should have access to my JQuery library?

What type of framework should I be looking at to solve my problem?

Answer (score 12):

You're actually asking more than one question.  I am currently analyzing the "what framework should I use" question for our company.  This entails a lot more than you think. Below is what I have so far, and as I get more details I will try to update this item.

In the meantime...

The question of architectural patterns is different from that of libraries or frameworks.

**[ARCHITECTURAL DESIGN PATTERNS](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript)** are useful for many reasons.  One reason would be to achieve loose coupling in your modules.   A great example of how to achieve loose coupling is found in the **[Mediator Pattern](http://arguments.callee.info/2009/05/18/javascript-design-patterns--mediator/)**.

**The question of which framework to use has many decision points:**

- **[JavaScript Famework Usage](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all)**
- **[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/?q=jquery,dojo,mootools,yui,extjs)**
- **[Comparison of JavaScript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)**

**Speed Tests:**

- **[Slick Speed](http://mootools.net/slickspeed/)**
- **[Task Speed](http://dante.dojotoolkit.org/taskspeed/)**
- **[Write your own test like this guy did](http://blog.creonfx.com/javascript/dojo-vs-jquery-vs-mootools-vs-prototype-performance-comparison)**

**These Are What I Consider FRAMEWORKS**:

- [**Dojo**](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/index.html)
- [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/): Is a framework only when 'umbrella' modules are included (can be used as a lone library)
- [**YUI**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/)
- [**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org/)

**I have decided to limit my FRAMEWORK CHOICES to**:

1. **[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/index.html)**: Toolkit, Desktop, Mobil, Graphics & Vectoring
2. **[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)**: Developer Tools, Infrastructure, Utilities, Widgets, gallery, Projects
3. **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**: Core, UI, Mobil, Plugins, Graphing, Visualization

**But...a breakdown of JavaScript LIBRARIES is also needed:**
MVC is the most commonly used front-end pattern.  However, my notes here are not yet complete. Even I am having trouble finding usage statistics on the items listed above.

**[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)** (MVC)
Designed more toward consuming REST data. Backbone has its own event system, and thus, competes with jQuery functionality.

**[Spine.js](http://spinejs.com/)** (MVC)

[**JavaScriptMVC**](http://jupiterjs.com/news/javascriptmvc-features) (MVC)
MVC integrated development tools; is used with jQuery; Highly modularized. Not yet sure if it can simply be considered a library or not...but daddy likey!

[**AngularJS**](http://angularjs.org/#/) (MVC)
Separation of concerns, loose coupling, and inversion of control. Two-way databinding

**[SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/)** (MVC)

**[YUILibrary](http://yuilibrary.com/)** (MVC)
This is really part of the overall YUI framework…but was listed in the original [source article](http://speakerdeck.com/u/addyosmani/p/large-scale-javascript-application-architecture).

**[Broke.js](https://github.com/brokenseal/broke-client)** (MVC)
Documentation is currently poor.

**[Fidel.js](http://jga.me/blog/2011/06/10/fidel)** (MVC)

**[Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/)** (MVC)
Designed more toward consuming REST data.

**[KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)** (MVVM)

QUESTIONS:

- Why are there so few outright MVVM implementations?
- Is Two-Way Binding the same thing as MVVM?
- If so, why do some of these libraries (that do two-way binding) consider themselves MVC?

**MODULAR JAVASCRIPT:** [**AMD**](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD), [**CommonJS**](http://www.commonjs.org/) **and Promises-Based Implementations:**
I am still outlining this area.  However, below are some areas I am using for inspiration.

- **[A previous question of mine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122507/where-does-jquery-fit-in-with-frameworks-like-javascriptmvc-backbonejs-sproutc/122647#122647)**
- **[ARTICLE: Writing Modular JavaScript With AMD, CommonJS & ES Harmony](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)**
- **[ARTICLE: My Thoughts on AMD](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2012/03/my-thoughts-on-amd/)**
- **[ARTICLE: Creating large-scale JavaScript Applications](http://speakerdeck.com/u/addyosmani/p/large-scale-javascript-application-architecture)**
- **[PRESENTATION: AMD Patters by John Hann](http://unscriptable.com/code/AMD-module-patterns/#0)**
- **[Essential jQuery Plugin Patterns by Addy Osmoni](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/)**

QUESTIONS:

- Are there different 'flavors' of AMD (various articles seem to say yes)?
- What does 'promises-based' mean?

**CREATING WIDGETS & PLUGINS:**
Once you decide on which flavor of AMD your modules should use you can actually begin writting something.

- [ARTICLE: Coding your First jQuery UI Plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/coding-your-first-jquery-ui-plugin/)
- [ARTICLE: The jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide6)

QUESTIONS:

- What is the difference between a plugin and a widget?

**GENERAL NOTES:** 
I would suggest looking at how each of your frameworks implement various modules.  Look at the code it takes to accomplish something.  Does it feel right?  Does it feel clunky?

**MY INITIAL FEELING:**
Looking at the trends, usage, speed and vastness of community support options...jQuery is way ahead.

**THE GOAL:**
The final goal is to choose a framework, any/all libraries and define a general approach for loading and creating loosely-coupled JavaScript Modules.

**Quantifying Cost by Risk:**
Quantiying cost outright is difficult, but you can explain-away risk. In your final desicion, you should also take into account the trends listed above.  But, in general, I would loosely break-up cost into 3 areas that define RISK:

- **Familiarity**: What is your team most familiar with now?
- **Ramping Up**: How much extra-effort would it take to get "ramped-up" on each framework and library?
- **Licensing**: Are there any snags here?

**Risk**: Once assessed, you can rightfully explain WHY you might rank one option as low, medium or high.

**@ErezCohen**

We are an ASP.NET shop, so we use Web API for our RESTFUL backend.  And since component-style JavaScript development is the future, we chose to use jQuery & RequireJS as a standard baseline on all our pages.  Additionally, we make heavy use of Deferreds in our controllers.

As for client-side MVC, too many of the “frameworks” mentioned are more fads than anything else (and many have waned in use). Additionally, it made more sense to treat MVC/MVVM capabilities as a one-off add-on when requirements dictated rather than a standard.  And, frankly, since we find making Ajax calls easy, brining-in vast frameworks to do simple data-binding seemed silly (the only real benefit is two-way binding for certain complex cases).  Besides, think about what a pain it would be to decouple some of these frameworks once they are no longer popular.

Of course, we have the talent to do so on our own…you may not.  If your crew isn’t very good with JavaScript, try Angular because it was developed for “designers” not programmers.  Alternatively, if your team is capable of rolling-their-own and wants a framework for controllers then jQuery Widget Factory is useful.  However, simple use of the Module Pattern for your controllers is fine too (that is what we do).  And...it works great...and is VERY clean.

Comment: I'm curious to know what have you select. + Have you considered Kendo As well?

Comment: Yes, we use Kendo controls today. The problem with Kendo MVC is the heavy coupling to its control set... you are dependent on Kendo. You become a Kendo shop. Besides, nowadays, no one set of controls will ever provide you all the capabilities you need. Kendo does great at some things and horrible at others. Meanwhile, other control libraries like Synchfusion or RGraph are lacking where Kendo is great. In the end, you have to use many toolsets to provide the experience requirements dictate. And, since Kendo MVC is so heavily coupled to Kendo controls…we don’t use that portion of Kendo.